# Java app can not find resource text files in jar

Tags: java, eclipse, embedded-resource, executable-jar

Getting the following error from executable jar. Runs fine in eclipse and files are present in jar.

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:171)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:157)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Unknown Source)
    at come.awana.app.utility.Utilities.createRecords(Utilities.java:37)
    at com.awana.app.gui.RecordDisplayPanel.<init>(RecordDisplayPanel.java:82)
    at com.awana.app.gui.GUIDriver.<init>(GUIDriver.java:36)
    at com.awana.app.gui.GUIDriver.InitalizeAndShowGUI(GUIDriver.java:65)
    at com.awana.app.gui.GUIDriver.access$0(GUIDriver.java:62)
    at com.awana.app.gui.GUIDriver$1.run(GUIDriver.java:54)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Getting files as follows:

```
URI resource = Utilities.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/names.txt").toURI();
names = createNameList(Paths.get(resource));
```

Trying to read the file:

```
private static List<String> createNameList(Path path){

    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

    try(BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, Charset.defaultCharset())){
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            temp.add(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /* do stuff with temp */
}
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the way the resource is trying to load but not sure how to correct. Any suggestions...

**EDIT**

Though I would post the corrected code for anyone else who comes across this later (since I hate when  people put 'fix it' and then don't show how they solved the problem...  Thanks MadProgrammer!

Getting resource files as follows:

```
InputStream resource  Utilities.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/names.txt");
names = createNameList(resource);
```

Reading the file:

```
private static List<String> createNameList(InputStream resource){

    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource))){
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            temp.add(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /* do stuff with temp */
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can use this with `Paths` and `Files`, but instead should either get the `InputStream` from the `URL` or use `Class#getResourceAsStream` instead

Comment: You are absolutely correct. That solved the problem changing the getResource() to getResourceAsStream() and changed the Files.newBufferedReader to reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource))

Comment: To be runnable on an other system with an other encoding, one should specify the encoding of the resource text. `new InputStreamReader(resource, encoding)`. Probably `Windows-1252`, Windows Latin-1.

Comment: Generally your life is easier if you use InputStreams when you deal with files in jars.